# Number of words with non-English characters, special characters such as punctuation, or digits at beginning or middle of word

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I need to count words with non-English characters, special characters such as punctuation, or digits at beginning or middle of word. 
I trying to do it with `re`, and now it seems like

```
begin_searcher = re.compile(r'[0-9]+[\w\-]')
middle_searcher = re.compile(r'[\w\-]+[0-9]+[\w\-]')
both_searcher = re.compile(r'[0-9]+[\w\-]+[0-9]+[\w\-]')
```

But it works completely wrong. Anyone, who knows `re` better me, please help.

I need to count this:

```
'asfas1254asffas'
'125safasffa'
'asd!asfg'
'asff#dasf'
'sex!!!!'
'safщовфау'
```

etc

Comment: What output are you expecting from this input?

Comment: sorry, I forget about it. I think `True-False` enough, or word if `True`, `None` if `False`. Anyway I'll change code after-all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it could help:

```
def find_alphabetic_words(self, text):
                    letters = ascii_letters
                    letters_nd_term = letters + "?!,."
                    return not any([set(text[:-1]).difference(letters),text[-1] not in letters_nd_term])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned "non-english" characters, I recommend using [regex](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) instead of stock `re`, because of the weak unicode support in the latter. Unless I misunderstood the question, you're looking for something like:

```
regex.match(ur'^\p{L}*[\p{P}\p{Nd}]*\p{L}+$', s) #
```

where `s` is expected to be a unicode object. This matches `u"123щовßß"` and `u"щов456ßß"` and rejects `u"щовßß!!!"`.

Comment: I cant use non-standart libs :( Thank you anyway.